# Powershell match a single string against multiple regexs?

Tags: regex, powershell

Is there a more 'powershelly' way of matching a single string against an array/collection of regexes other than iterating through each one in turn?

What I'd really like to be able to do is something this

$database.Name -match $includeRegexArray

Given the way Powershell works it feels like there should be a nicer solution than writing a function to iterate over the array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select-String will accept an array of regex patterns:

```
Select-String $includeRegexArray -inp $database.Name
```

Comment: Perfect! I was sure there was a nicer way of doing it