# R: grep multiple strings at once

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame with 1 variable and 5,000 rows, where each element is a string.

```
1. "Am open about my feelings."                   
2. "Take charge."                                 
3. "Talk to a lot of different people at parties."
4. "Make friends easily."                         
5. "Never at a loss for words."                   
6. "Don't talk a lot."                            
7. "Keep in the background."                      
   .....
5000. "Speak softly."
```

I need to find and output row numbers that correspond to 3 specific elements. 
Currently, I use the following:

```
grep("Take charge." ,  df[,1]) 
grep("Make friends easily.",  df[,1])  
grep("Make friends easily.",  df[,1])
```

And get the following output: 
    [1] 2 [2] 4 [3] 5000

Question 1. Is there a way to make syntax more succinct, so I do not have to use grep and  df[,1] on every single line?

Questions 2. If so, how to output a single numerical array of the necessary row positions, so the result would look something like this?

```
2, 4, 5000
```

What I tried so far.
    grep("Take charge." , "Make friends easily.","Make friends easily.",
    df[,1])  # this didn't work

I tried to create a vector, called m1, that contains all three elements and then grep(m1, df[,1])  # this didn't work either

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [grep using a character vector with multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7597559/903061) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9537797/903061) (substituting `grepl` for `regexpr`).

Comment: Just in case the answers aren't clear, you have options such as `patterns = c("Take charge.", "Make friends easily.")`, an easy way is `which(grepl(paste(patterns, collapse = "|"), df[,1]))`. This is standard regex where `.` matches any single character---if you want to match a literal `"."` escape it in your patterns, e.g., `"Take charge\\."`.

Comment: But Gabor has a good point in his answer--if these are complete, exact matches then a non-regex solution will be simpler and more efficient.

Comment: I tried both solutions, for some reason your solution worked perfectly but Gabor's not, maybe I did something wrong though. Anyways thank you for your input! I very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are exact matches use this where `phrases` is a character vector of the phrases you want to match:

```
match(phrases, df[, 1])
```

This also works provided no phrase is a substring of another phrase:

```
grep(phrases, df[, 1])
```

Comment: Since OP isn't clear about uniqueness, probably worth mentioning the difference between `match(prhases, df[, 1])` and `which(df[, 1] %in% phrases)`.