# Finding out which pattern was matched when using multiple patterns

Tags: r

I am looking to find out which pattern is matched in a list of file names. I can find out if a match was found, but not which pattern was matched.

```r
  local_pattern <- data.frame(
    condition = c("umhfl","dmhfl", "umhfr", "dmhfr", "shfr", "vshfr", "vshfl"),
    filename = c("*Upward motion*HF*Left*.csv", "*Downward motion*HF*Left*.csv", "*UHFR*.csv", "*DHFR*.csv", "*SHFR*.csv", "*VSHFR*.csv", "*VSHFL*.csv")
  )

## matching a sample file name
pattern_matched <- grep(paste(glob2rx(local_pattern[,2]), collapse = "|"), "./csv files/DHFR 2019-04-09 04.59 PM_001.csv", value = F)
```

What I would like to see is the pattern that was matched rather than simply a TRUE that a match was found.

Comment: Why not change `value=F` to `value=TRUE`.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me which pattern was found in a particular file name.

Comment: Did you already have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537797/r-grep-match-one-string-against-multiple-patterns

Comment: Indeed, possible duplicate of the first answer over there - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538033/496803 - which returns a TRUE/FALSE matrix for every possibility.

Comment: @Sven, similar but not the same. The match pattern has wildcards here but the solution does not work here.

Comment: Instead of using logical-OR (regex-`"|"`)  you probably need to use `sapply` on a vector of separate patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `str_detect` from `stringr` that is vectorised over `string` and `pattern`:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect("./csv files/DHFR 2019-04-09 04.59 PM_001.csv",
           glob2rx(local_pattern[, 2]))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

so that

```
local_pattern[str_detect("./csv files/DHFR 2019-04-09 04.59 PM_001.csv", glob2rx(local_pattern[,2])), 2]
# [1] *DHFR*.csv
```

Comment: How do I know that the DHFR pattern was matched rather than one of the others?

Comment: This works great, thank you! Concise and outputs just the right code. The only modification I made was to output column 1 from local_pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If there are fewer than 10 patterns to match, you can collect information with `PERL` style captures in base R. First build a pattern with `(...)` to capture.

```
pat <- paste(glob2rx(local_pattern$filename), collapse = ")|(")
pat <- paste0("(", pat, ")")
```

Assign the text string to variable for now:

```
x <- "./csv files/DHFR 2019-04-09 04.59 PM_001.csv"
```

Use `regexpr` or with more effort, `gregexpr`, for multiple matches:

```
m <- regexpr(pat, x, perl = TRUE)
sel <- which(attr(m, "capture.length") > 0)
```

Collect the desired information:

```
local_pattern[sel,]
>   condition   filename
> 4     dmhfr *DHFR*.csv

regmatches(x, m)
> [1] "./csv files/DHFR 2019-04-09 04.59 PM_001.csv"
```